# Circuit component

Tags: components

What is this circular component with two parallel lines in it? I've never seen this before

[image]

Comment: can you share more info.. might be a mic

Comment: I'm dealing with reaction wheels and this circuit is the ON/OFF telemetry circuit between the reaction wheel and the FPGA. could this symbol mean reaction wheel? @Umar

Comment: May be others can get you more exact answer. I feel, it is a sensor of some sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a symbol for [DC Voltage](http://www.clker.com/clipart-13369.html).

Comment: ... but with the polarity missing...

Comment: There's a defined ground point in the circuit,  it's a bit sloppy but usually the meaning will be quite clear.

Comment: I rather would say (instead of "power supply") DC voltage.

Comment: It's a symbol for dc /power/